# Covering space of a compact connected surface without boundary is a compact surface without boundary

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Let $p: X' \rightarrow X$ be an n-sheeted cover of $X$. I proved that $X$ being compact implies that $X'$ is compact in the standard way. I started with an open cover of $X'$, projected it under $p$, used compactification to get a finite subset that covers $X$, and then took the inverse image of those subsets to get a finite sub collection of the original open cover.

How can I use this local information in conjunction with compactness of $X'$ and $X$ to show that $X'$ does not have a boundary?

Also, how can I show that $E(X')=nE(X)$ where $E$ is the Euler characteristic.

Comment: Why should you have $E(X') = 6 E(X)$? Take for example $n = 1$ in which case $p$ will be a homeomorphism.

Comment: oops was supposed to be n.. Thanks!

Comment: You should tell us which theorems you are allowed to use.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x'\in X'$. Write $p(x')=x$. Let $U$ an open subset which is a chart of $X$ and which contains $x$ such that $p^{-1}(U)=V_1,...,V_n$ such that the restriction $p:V_i\rightarrow U$ is a diffeomorphism. Suppose $x'\in V_{i_0}$. Since $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$  (the domain of a chart) so is $V_{i_0}$, we deduce that $x'$ has an open neighborhood diffeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and that the boundary of $X'$ is empty.

Comment: When you say that $U$ is a chart of X you mean that there is some map that maps $U$ homeomorphically onto a neighborhood of X? So you are then identifying this neighborhood with $U$ itself, which allows the make $p^{-1}(U)$ to make sense, but what is really going on is $p^{-1}(\alpha(U))$ Where $\alpha$ parameterizes a neighborhood in X, correct?

This question is from my algebraic topology class where we haven't talked about charts at all. But this answer makes sense, thank you.

Comment: A chart means a neighborhood homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on what type of manifold you are working with? If you were using an atlas that locally parameterizes a smooth manifold then the charts would have to be diffeomorphisms.

Comment: But what about showing that the Euler Characteristic of the cover space is n times the Euler characteristic of the base?